# C# Install class isn't executed

Tags: c#, installation

I've made an simple installation class:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class MyCustumAction : Installer
{
    public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
    {
        base.Install(stateSaver);
        string value = Context.Parameters["targetdir"];

        throw new Exception("Contact?? " + value);

        WriteLog(value);
    }

    private void WriteLog(string message)
    {
        using(FileStream f = File.Create(@"C:\ik ben nieuw.txt"))
        {
            using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(f))
            {
                w.WriteLine("Dag van installatie: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                w.WriteLine(message);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my Setup project I've done the following:

- Add project output - primary output of my assembly
- Add a Custom Action on the Install directory (Custom Actions view)
- Set CustumActionData to '/targetdir="[TARGETDIR]\"'
- Build my assembly and build the setup project

During the installation, the Exception is not thrown. Why not? It seems that my class isn't invoked. What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

When I create a seperate project with only the installer class in it and add this ont to my project ouput and set the custum action properly, I do get the exception!

Now I am wondering why this same file doesn't get invoked in my own (winforms) assembly..

Comment: Just a side note: You should really use using with your disposable resources instead of calling Dispose like that.

Comment: Thnx for the tip. I've modified my code.

Comment: Same with the `FileStream`, please.`

Comment: Ah forget about that one. But it's modified now =]

Comment: are you in Vista/Win7? are you running from the setup.exe?

Comment: I'm using Win XP and I'm using the msi file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decorate your class with the `RunInstaller` attribute.  This provides more detail.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.runinstallerattribute.aspx

Comment: I have the attribute, but I still don't get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Have you decorated your class with

> [RunInstaller(true)]

?

Comment: Yes I have and still I don't get the exception

Answer (score 0):

I have some notes from when I was trying to solve this same problem:

> to install on Vista ensure you
>   initiate from the Setup.exe, not from
>   the Msi

Even if you are on XP perhaps you should try running from the setup.exe